# appropriate preposition with 'influence'

Tags: prepositions

> The influence of three oxidizing systems **on/over** the reduction of
>   concentration of water solutions of formaldehyde has been studies.

What should be appropriate use of preposition in this case and why? I have known that influence can take up to three prepositions according to use like, influence **with** person, influence **on** something. But I have also seen example like

> The kid next door is a bad/good influence **on** Kevin.

Someone clarify which preposition to use in what context.

Comment: I edited your question to fix several spelling errors.  Since you did spell each of these words correctly elsewhere in your question, I assumed this was simple oversight.  I strongly encourage you to be punctilious in avoiding spelling mistakes,  even in casual communication, as this is one of the fundamental ways native speakers judge your English ability.

Comment: Here you would say that you "know", not that you "have known". And "has been *studied*".

Answer (score 1):

Both "on" and "over" are acceptable prepositions to use with "influence"; however in this context of a scientific experiment, "on" is probably the more idiomatic choice.  In most contexts, "on" implies a *variable* or *unknown* degree of influence.  Example:

> This study measured the **influence** of small concentrations of various environmental contaminants **on** the mating habits of Columba livia domestica (the common domestic pigeon)

"Over" implies a greater degree of influence, or influence over a wider range.  For example:

> The senators have repeatedly questioned whether the President has had an undue **influence over** the investigation.

Here we could use "on", but it would change the meaning, as the writer wants to say that the senators implied the President *did* improperly influence the investigation.

Comment: What about influence 'with'? When do we use that?

Comment: @RitwikBhattacharyya  Those three aren't the complete list.  There's also influence *in*, *under*, *by*, *upon*, [and various others](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=influence+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3).  Most of these -- including *with* -- use the common interpretation of the preposition.